# How to run a PyCharm project while passing environment variables from command line

Tags: python, pycharm, jython, sikuli

I have an automation test framework built using Jython intertpreter in Pycharm. I'm using Sikuli and Selenium in this framework and I want to eventually start running this project from Jenkins. In order to do that, I want to get this running via command line first. But when I try running this via command line, I get this error. Does anyone know how to pass in environment variables via command line?

[Debug config screenshot & running via command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pfrc.png)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've found a way by setting these environment variables in windows and then running the tests by `C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jython.exe -Dpython.path=C:\uiautomation C:/uiautomation/TestRunner/test_runner.py`